# Find an element from a array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array which spans as follows. So the example to understand is consider a block with 6 faces. The array contains the index in this array from which the faces for a particular colour will start.

```
array[0] 0
array[1] 2
array[2] 4
array[3] 5
```

so this means that colour 0 is for faces 0 and 1, colour 1 is for faces 2 and 3, 
and colour 2 is only for face 4

But the array will not always look like this. if there is a block with just a single colour the array would look like

```
array[0] 0
array[1] 1
```

which means face 0 is coloured with 0 color, and faces 1,2,3,4,5 are coloured with color 1

I will get an input as the face number and need to find the corresponding colour

I tried it with a for loop

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.size(); ++index) 
{ 
    if (array[index] == input) 
    { 
        return index; 
    } 
    if (array[index] < input) 
    { 
        return index - 1; 
    } 
}
```

but the answer is not always correct . Can this be done with `while` . Please help

Comment: Show us your for-loop then?

Comment: show what you have tried and what the problem was (either the incorrect output or the error message if there was one). A for loop is a good start, and you most likely just made a small mistake, but we can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: Try binary search.

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < array.lenth(); ++index)
    {
        if (array(index) == input)
        {
   return index;
        }

        if (array(index) < input)
        {
           return index - 1;
        }
    }

Comment: @Divya Please [edit] the question with all of the relevant information. In this instance: with [mcve].

Comment: "array[1] 2" means "subscript 1 is for 2 and 3 " ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to find the largest index of the array which is less or equal to the given input.

Then you can use the following with binary search.

```
std::size_t getIndexFor(const std::vector<int>& v, int input)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), input);
    if (it != v.begin() && (it == v.end() || *it != input)) {
        --it;
    }
    return std::distance(v.begin(), it);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Lx5IF8)

A simpler (and linear) way:

```
std::size_t getIndexFor(const std::vector<int>& v, int input)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int e){ return e > input;});
    if (it == v.begin()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("input not handled");
    }
    --it;
    return std::distance(v.begin(), it);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/o2miu2)

Comment: Bingo! A bit too complicated though for a beginner

Comment: yes thats correct and precise way .. i am new so could not frame the question as you did.. but i just have an array and not a vector ...as in to use the .begin and all capability should it be a vector ... my input will just be an array ..

Comment: It could be a subscript greator than the input as well... So as i might get the arranegment as follows:  a[0] -- 0

Comment: @Divya If you are using arrays, your compiler should have complained at `array.size()`, but you can still use the free functions `std::begin(array)` and `std::end(array)`.

Comment: Both [logarithm search Demo](https://ideone.com/o3DeH6) and [Linear search Demo](https://ideone.com/G1tekn) give correct result for `0, 1, 2, 3` and `4, 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You would just do the same thing, looping through the array to search for the term you want. Of course if it's a sorted array this would be much faster, so something similar to prehaps:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
 if(array[i] == itemToFind){
     break;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the right solution, just change `array[index] < input` into `array[index] > input`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> array = {0, 2, 4, 5};
int subs(int input)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < array.size(); ++index) 
    { 
        if (array[index] == input) 
        { 
            return index; 
        } 
        if (array[index] > input) 
        { 
            return index - 1; 
        } 
    }
    return -1;
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        std::cout<<"input: "<<i<<" "<<"color: "<<subs(i)<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
input: 0 color: 0
input: 1 color: 0
input: 2 color: 1
input: 3 color: 1
input: 4 color: 2
input: 5 color: 3
```

Comment: no that does not work either the array isn ot always arranged in the same manner

Comment: @Divya could you give an example of a different arrangement when this doesn't work?

Comment: @bigeast I think OP wants to return last index if there is no much, instead of  `return -1;` return `return array.size() - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I used the for loop also but using break after one if condition that checks if the input equals any element in the array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string arr = " ";
    int x;
    cout << "Enter your input";
    cin >> x;
    for (int i =0; i< arr.length(); i++ ){
        if (arr[i] == x){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, maybe simpler solution:

```
int findIndex( const std::vector<int>& vec, int input )
{
    int count = vec.size()-1;
    for ( auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); it++)
    {
        if ( *it<=input )
        {
            return count;
        }
        count--;
    }

    return -1; // if nothing found
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec { 0,2,4,5 };

    for ( int input=0; input <=5; input++)
    {
        std::cout <<  findIndex( vec, input ) << " " << input << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
3 5
```